# How to sort with incomplete ordering?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have a list of elements to sort and a comparison function `cmp(x,y)` which decides if `x` should appear before `y` or after `y`. The catch is that some elements do not have a defined order. The `cmp` function returns "*don't care*".

Example: Input: `[A,B,C,D]`, and `C > D`, `B > D`. Output: many correct answers, e.g. `[D,C,B,A]` or `[A,D,B,C]`. All I need is one output from all possible outputs..

I was not able to use the Python's `sort` for this and my solution is <del>the old-fashioned bubble-sort</del> to start with an empty list and insert one element at a time to the right place to keep the list sorted all the time.

Is it possible to use the built-in `sort`/`sorted` function for this purpose? What would be the key?

Comment: Why is python's sort wrong? By definition, a complete ordering is a valid partial ordering. Assuming that you return "equal" instead of "don't care", python's sort will always give you one of the possible answers.

Comment: @Andrew it's correct that a complete ordering is a valid partial ordering, but Python's sort will _not_ always give you a complete ordering that's compatible with your partial cmp function (and nor will any standard sort algorithm like quicksort or mergesort).

Comment: @PaulHankin Yes I just finished modifying my comment with how to modify the cmp function to get the ordering. Mid-morning brain fart...

Comment: Bubble sort cannot sort [A,D, A,C,A,B] with C>D and B>D. If your "don't care" is consistent to null-like-non-comparision, just put all non-comparable elements aside and sort the rest.

Comment: @AlexanderAnikin You're right. Thank you for spotting the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to use the built-in sort for this. Instead, you need to implement a [Topological Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Comment: And it'll be worst-case `O(n**2)` if all you have to work with is the comparator, since you might have to perform all pairwise comparisons to locate graph edges.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in sort method requires that `cmp` imposes a *total ordering*. It doesn't work if the comparisons are inconsistent. If it returns that A < B one time it must always return that, and it must return that B > A if the arguments are reversed.

You can make your `cmp` implementation work if you introduce an arbitrary tiebreaker. If two elements don't have a defined order, make one up. You could return `cmp(id(a), id(b))` for instance -- compare the objects by their arbitrary ID numbers.

Comment: Two elements may have an implicit order without any explicit one. For example, A < B, B < C. Then A and C have no given order, but you can't just "make one up", since to get a correct total ordering you have to infer that A < C.

Comment: Or to put my comment another way -- if you extend cmp like you suggest, you get most of the properties of a total order, but it may not be transitive.

Comment: @PaulHankin In my case the ordering is "sane" where it is defined. Basically, the elements are non-empty sets and the function is "x is a proper subset of y", i.e.transitive (A < B and B < C implies A < C). Is this sufficient to safely add the "tiebreaker"?

Comment: I don't think so. Suppose A is a subset of B, C is neither a superset nor a subset of both A and B, and id(B) < id(C) < id(A). Then A < B, B < C, but C < A.

Comment: "The built-in sort method requires that cmp imposes a total ordering" - I tend to agree that this is the case but do you know if it's officially documented anywhere in Python documentation?