# Sorting when compare-function could return "don't know" for certain pairs

Tags: sorting, language-agnostic, topological-sort

I would like to sort objects (or possibly rows of a datase) in a certain way. Primarily based on `time`, but this value can be NULL. I have a second value `sequence` which is a number which gives an order, but it may have a number which doesn't equal the order of the `time` column anymore. So it should at least sort the times in order.

Let's say I have an array/db with the following content:

```
id  time   sequence
 2  11:35  46
 4  NULL   48
 5  11:40  99
 6  NULL   49
 8  11:45  51
 9  11:50  52
 7  NULL   53
 3  NULL   54
 1  11:55  55
```

I would wantthe end-result to be like this

```
id  time   sequence
 2  11:35  46
 4  NULL   48
 6  NULL   49
 5  11:40  99
 8  11:45  51
 9  11:50  52
 7  NULL   53
 3  NULL   54
 1  11:55  55
```

A simple compare function would look something like this (pseudocode)

```
int compare(a, b)
{
    if(a->time !== null && b->time !== null)
        return (int)a->time - (int)b->time;

    return a->sequence - b->sequence;
}
```

But a generic sort-call will of course limit its number of compare-function calls. So if it compares ids `5/1`, `5/3` and `1/3` it will have determined an order and produce this result.

```
id  time   sequence
 2  11:35  46
 4  NULL   48
 6  NULL   49
 8  11:45  51
 9  11:50  52
 7  NULL   53
 3  NULL   54
 5  11:40  99
 1  11:55  55
```

I would like to give my compare function to say something like "don't know" for certain comparisons. Namelijk when a row with a `time` filled is compared to one without. So that the sort-function is forced to look further. I've tried returning 0 in that case for instance, but that doesn't solve the problem. Is there a name for this sort of mechanism? Is there a different way to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort with incomplete ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768575/how-to-sort-with-incomplete-ordering)

Comment: Relasted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480640/what-is-the-best-way-to-sort-a-partially-ordered-list https://stackoverflow.com/q/51429309/2509

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, you cannot sort by just comparing any two elements, because you do not have a total order.

You seem to be very sure of the resulting order though.

Let's take another instance, because expectations are unclear to me:

```
id  time   sequence
 2  11:35  103
 5  11:40  51
 8  11:45  28
 9  11:50  50
 1  11:55  99
```

where should all the NULL time go and why?

```
 4  NULL   48
 6  NULL   49
 7  NULL   53
 3  NULL   54
```

It seems difficult to find a rule for placing the NULL once we sorted the non NULL!
What probably better fits your expectations is the result from a procedural algorithm, like this for example:

1. sort by sequence first
2. then let well defined times move up as long as there is a larger time above

Written like this, Stage 2 looks like a bubble sort restricted to indices with non NULL times... You could call that a sparse bubble sort.

The resulting order is always the same whatever the original order, so it is not ambiguous.
I think that it's because stage 1) is a total order.
If you would introduce NULL in sequence column, I'm not even sure that you would end up with a non ambiguous sort...
Maybe you can call that a multi-stage partial sort.